# Problem with the new version of kotlinx-coroutines-play-services into my code

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines.flow

I already added coroutine play services into my code, everything was working find, but after updating coroutines to the version 1.3.2, my application crash and give me the error bellow, but into the stack trace it is not possible to see the origin of the error in my code, I tried to use the breack points and then I notice that de error occurred into the cancelation of the flow`awaitClose {cancel()}` . The stack trace is:

```
    2021-08-04 09:40:30.976 11200-11200/com.kola.kolaapplication.dev E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: 'awaitClose { yourCallbackOrListener.cancel() }' should be used in the end of callbackFlow block.
    Otherwise, a callback/listener may leak in case of external cancellation.
    Process: com.kola.kolaapplication.dev, PID: 11200
    See callbackFlow API documentation for the details.
2021-08-04 09:40:30.976 11200-11200/com.kola.kolaapplication.dev E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: 'awaitClose { yourCallbackOrListener.cancel() }' should be used in the end of callbackFlow block.
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.CallbackFlowBuilder.collectTo(Builders.kt:362)
    Process: com.kola.kolaapplication.dev, PID: 11200
    Otherwise, a callback/listener may leak in case of external cancellation.
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.CallbackFlowBuilder$collectTo$1.invokeSuspend(Unknown Source:15)
    See callbackFlow API documentation for the details.
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: 'awaitClose { yourCallbackOrListener.cancel() }' should be used in the end of callbackFlow block.
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.CallbackFlowBuilder.collectTo(Builders.kt:362)
    Otherwise, a callback/listener may leak in case of external cancellation.
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.resume(DispatchedTask.kt:234)
    See callbackFlow API documentation for the details.
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.CallbackFlowBuilder$collectTo$1.invokeSuspend(Unknown Source:15)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.resumeUnconfined(DispatchedTask.kt:190)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.CallbackFlowBuilder.collectTo(Builders.kt:362)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.dispatch(DispatchedTask.kt:161)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.resume(DispatchedTask.kt:234)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.CallbackFlowBuilder$collectTo$1.invokeSuspend(Unknown Source:15)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.dispatchResume(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:398)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.resumeUnconfined(DispatchedTask.kt:190)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.cancel(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:184)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.dispatch(DispatchedTask.kt:161)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.resume(DispatchedTask.kt:234)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.parentCancelled$kotlinx_coroutines_core(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:191)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.dispatchResume(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:398)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.resumeUnconfined(DispatchedTask.kt:190)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.ChildContinuation.invoke(JobSupport.kt:1474)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.cancel(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:184)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.dispatch(DispatchedTask.kt:161)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.notifyCancelling(JobSupport.kt:1499)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.dispatchResume(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:398)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.parentCancelled$kotlinx_coroutines_core(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:191)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.tryMakeCancelling(JobSupport.kt:795)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.ChildContinuation.invoke(JobSupport.kt:1474)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.cancel(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:184)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.makeCancelling(JobSupport.kt:755)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.notifyCancelling(JobSupport.kt:1499)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.cancelImpl$kotlinx_coroutines_core(JobSupport.kt:671)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.parentCancelled$kotlinx_coroutines_core(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:191)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.tryMakeCancelling(JobSupport.kt:795)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.parentCancelled(JobSupport.kt:637)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.ChildContinuation.invoke(JobSupport.kt:1474)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.makeCancelling(JobSupport.kt:755)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.ChildHandleNode.invoke(JobSupport.kt:1465)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.notifyCancelling(JobSupport.kt:1499)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.cancelImpl$kotlinx_coroutines_core(JobSupport.kt:671)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.notifyCancelling(JobSupport.kt:1499)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.tryMakeCancelling(JobSupport.kt:795)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.parentCancelled(JobSupport.kt:637)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.tryMakeCancelling(JobSupport.kt:795)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.makeCancelling(JobSupport.kt:755)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.ChildHandleNode.invoke(JobSupport.kt:1465)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.makeCancelling(JobSupport.kt:755)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.cancelImpl$kotlinx_coroutines_core(JobSupport.kt:671)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.notifyCancelling(JobSupport.kt:1499)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.cancelImpl$kotlinx_coroutines_core(JobSupport.kt:671)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.parentCancelled(JobSupport.kt:637)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.tryMakeCancelling(JobSupport.kt:795)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.parentCancelled(JobSupport.kt:637)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.ChildHandleNode.invoke(JobSupport.kt:1465)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.makeCancelling(JobSupport.kt:755)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.ChildHandleNode.invoke(JobSupport.kt:1465)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.notifyCancelling(JobSupport.kt:1499)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.cancelImpl$kotlinx_coroutines_core(JobSupport.kt:671)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.notifyCancelling(JobSupport.kt:1499)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.tryMakeCancelling(JobSupport.kt:795)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.parentCancelled(JobSupport.kt:637)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.tryMakeCancelling(JobSupport.kt:795)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.makeCancelling(JobSupport.kt:755)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.ChildHandleNode.invoke(JobSupport.kt:1465)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.makeCancelling(JobSupport.kt:755)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.cancelImpl$kotlinx_coroutines_core(JobSupport.kt:671)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.notifyCancelling(JobSupport.kt:1499)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.cancelImpl$kotlinx_coroutines_core(JobSupport.kt:671)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.parentCancelled(JobSupport.kt:637)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.tryMakeCancelling(JobSupport.kt:795)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.makeCancelling(JobSupport.kt:755)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.cancelImpl$kotlinx_coroutines_core(JobSupport.kt:671)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.parentCancelled(JobSupport.kt:637)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.ChildHandleNode.invoke(JobSupport.kt:1465)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.notifyCancelling(JobSupport.kt:1499)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.tryMakeCompletingSlowPath(JobSupport.kt:900)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.tryMakeCompleting(JobSupport.kt:863)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.cancelMakeCompleting(JobSupport.kt:696)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.cancelImpl$kotlinx_coroutines_core(JobSupport.kt:667)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.cancelInternal(JobSupport.kt:632)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.cancel(JobSupport.kt:617)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobKt__JobKt.cancel(Job.kt:561)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobKt.cancel(Unknown Source:1)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobKt__JobKt.cancel$default(Job.kt:560)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobKt.cancel$default(Unknown Source:1)
        at androidx.lifecycle.CloseableCoroutineScope.close(ViewModel.kt:51)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel.closeWithRuntimeException(ViewModel.java:188)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel.clear(ViewModel.java:134)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelStore.clear(ViewModelStore.java:62)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerViewModel.clearNonConfigState(FragmentManagerViewModel.java:199)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.destroy(FragmentStateManager.java:772)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:350)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:112)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.ChildHandleNode.invoke(JobSupport.kt:1465)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1647)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.notifyCancelling(JobSupport.kt:1499)
2021-08-04 09:40:30.980 11200-11200/com.kola.kolaapplication.dev E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3126)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.parentCancelled(JobSupport.kt:637)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.tryMakeCancelling(JobSupport.kt:795)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchDestroy(FragmentManager.java:3105)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.ChildHandleNode.invoke(JobSupport.kt:1465)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performDestroy(Fragment.java:3214)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.makeCancelling(JobSupport.kt:755)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.destroy(FragmentStateManager.java:774)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.notifyCancelling(JobSupport.kt:1499)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.cancelImpl$kotlinx_coroutines_core(JobSupport.kt:671)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:350)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.parentCancelled(JobSupport.kt:637)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.tryMakeCompletingSlowPath(JobSupport.kt:900)
        at androidx.fragment.app.SpecialEffectsController$FragmentStateManagerOperation.complete(SpecialEffectsController.java:742)
        at androidx.fragment.app.SpecialEffectsController$Operation.cancel(SpecialEffectsController.java:594)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.ChildHandleNode.invoke(JobSupport.kt:1465)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.tryMakeCompleting(JobSupport.kt:863)
        at androidx.fragment.app.SpecialEffectsController.forceCompleteAllOperations(SpecialEffectsController.java:329)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.notifyCancelling(JobSupport.kt:1499)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.cancelMakeCompleting(JobSupport.kt:696)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3130)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchDestroy(FragmentManager.java:3105)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.cancelImpl$kotlinx_coroutines_core(JobSupport.kt:667)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.tryMakeCompletingSlowPath(JobSupport.kt:900)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchDestroy(FragmentController.java:334)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onDestroy(FragmentActivity.java:330)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.cancelInternal(JobSupport.kt:632)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.tryMakeCompleting(JobSupport.kt:863)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onDestroy(AppCompatActivity.java:242)
        at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:8865)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.cancel(JobSupport.kt:617)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.cancelMakeCompleting(JobSupport.kt:696)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1316)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobKt__JobKt.cancel(Job.kt:561)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.cancelImpl$kotlinx_coroutines_core(JobSupport.kt:667)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4539)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4572)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobKt.cancel(Unknown Source:1)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.cancelInternal(JobSupport.kt:632)
        at android.app.servertransaction.DestroyActivityItem.execute(DestroyActivityItem.java:39)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.cancel(JobSupport.kt:617)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:145)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobKt__JobKt.cancel$default(Job.kt:560)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1830)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobKt.cancel$default(Unknown Source:1)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobKt__JobKt.cancel(Job.kt:561)
        at androidx.lifecycle.CloseableCoroutineScope.close(ViewModel.kt:51)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobKt.cancel(Unknown Source:1)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6914)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel.closeWithRuntimeException(ViewModel.java:188)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobKt__JobKt.cancel$default(Job.kt:560)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel.clear(ViewModel.java:134)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:588)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.JobKt.cancel$default(Unknown Source:1)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelStore.clear(ViewModelStore.java:62)
        at androidx.lifecycle.CloseableCoroutineScope.close(ViewModel.kt:51)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerViewModel.clearNonConfigState(FragmentManagerViewModel.java:199)

**Coroutine into my gradle file:**
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.3.2'
```

My code:

```
val curentUserDocRef: DocumentReference
    get() = firestoreInstance.document(
        commonFireStoreRefKeyWord.USERS_COLLECTION_REF.plus(
            "/${FireStoreAuthUtil.getUserUID()}"
        )
    )

 fun saveUserToFireStore(newUser: KUser): Flow<FirebaseResponseType<KUser>> = callbackFlow{

    curentUserDocRef.get().addOnSuccessListener { documentSnapshot ->
        //Get the user into firebase firestore
        if (!documentSnapshot.exists()) {
           //If the user does not exist, we save it
            curentUserDocRef.set(newUser)
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    
                try {
                        
                 this.trySend(FirebaseResponseType.FirebaseSuccessResponse(newUser)).isSuccess
                } catch (ex: Exception) {
                   ex.printStackTrace()
                   Log(ex.message)
                   cancel()
                }
        } else {
            // If the user already save, we don't save it anymore
            val userData = documentSnapshot.toObject(KUser::class.java)
            try {
                this.trySend(FirebaseResponseType.FirebaseSuccessResponse(userData)).isSuccess
            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                ex.printStackTrace()
                cLog(ex.message)
                cancel()
            }
        }
    }.addOnFailureListener {
        it.printStackTrace()
        cLog(it.message)
        try {
            this.trySend(FirebaseResponseType.FirebaseErrorResponse(it)).isSuccess
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            ex.printStackTrace()
            cLog(ex.message)
            printLogD(TAG, ex.message ?: "")
        }
        cancel()
    }

    try {
        awaitClose {
            cancel()  // **I think the error occured here**
        }
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        ex.printStackTrace()
        cLog(ex.message)
        printLogD(TAG, ex.message ?: "")
    }

}
```

Into the preview version of coroutine play service, I was using offer() intead of trySend(), But into coroutine coroutines-play-services:1.3.2, the offer() method is deprecated, they ask to use trySend().

What should be done to resolve this problem Please, I have been looking for the solution for a week already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem when I change **offer** by **trySend** in my callbackFlow.

I notice that when I close the scope instead of the channel my application crashes.

So to solve my problem, I used `awaitClose { channel.close() }` instead of `awaitClose { cancel() }`.

Comment: Thanks you Yvana I did the same and it solved my problem,

Comment: Im a bit confused - inside awaitClose you should be removing the listener you added to firebase not cancelling the coroutine or closing the channel - in fact the channel should already be closed by the time awaitClose invokes the block as thats the point of awaitClose: from the docs "Suspends the current coroutine until the channel is either closed or cancelled and invokes the given block before resuming the coroutine."

Comment: Indeed the accepted answer is incorrect.

Comment: I made the same changes with trySend in my callbackFlow, but it showed this error, ```Builder inference lambda contains inapplicable calls so {1} cant be inferred. It could be resolved only with unrestricted builder inference. Please use -Xunrestricted-builder-inference compiler flag to enable it.```

Comment: your code worked but I am confused and I have same question as @nbransby can you explain this please. Thank you.